# Как реализовать добавление в словарь элементов?

Tags: python, словари

```
n = int(input())
sl = {}
for i in range(n):
  a = list(map(int(input())))
  sl[n//2] =
```

к примеру на вход подаются такие числа:

```
3
1 2 3 4
3 2 3 1
4 1 5 3
```

пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы в словарь попадал ключ - это число из строки матрицы, индекс которой n // 2, а значение к этому ключу  – список отсортированных по возрастанию нечетных чисел того же столбца и той же строки (без числа-ключа) без повторений

проблема в том что ключ n//2 я добавляю ,но к нему нужно ведь добавлять и значение сразу же, а как его добавлять я не знаю, ибо нужно же в качестве значения взять числа из строки и столбца, а если к примеру только ввели 1 строку, то столбца же всего нет, чтобы взять значения

примерно, как должно получиться в итоге(входные данные к этому рез-ту написаны выше в примере):

```
{3: [1, 3, 5], 2: [1, 3], 1: [3]}
```

**UPDATE:**

**Zhihar**

**Вывод**

```
{1: [1, 3, 5], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 3, 5], 4: [1, 3, 5], 5: [1, 3, 5]}
```

**Вывод**

```
{1: [3, 5], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 3, 5], 4: [1, 3, 5], 5: [1, 3]}
```

**UPDATE 2.0:**

Более четкая формулировка:

**Формат ввода**

Вводится число n – количество строк в списке.

Затем вводятся строки из чисел, записанных через пробел.

**Формат вывода**

Вывести словарь, в котором ключи – это числа из строки матрицы, индекс которой n // 2, а значения – список отсортированных по возрастанию нечетных чисел того же столбца и той же строки (без числа-ключа) без повторений. Если в строке встречаются одинаковые числа, то значения добавляются в один список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то должно получиться как-то так:

без оптимизаций, более-менее в лоб

```
# получить входные данные от пользователя
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(int(input()))]


# проанализировать данные
dictionary = {}

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        key = matrix[i][j]

        # проанализировать строку и получить нечетные значения
        line1 = [matrix[i][x] for x in range(len(matrix[i])) if matrix[i][x] % 2]

        # проанализировать столбец и получить нечетные значения
        line2 = [matrix[x][j] for x in range(len(matrix)) if matrix[x][j] % 2]

        # добавить в словарь
        if key not in dictionary:
            dictionary[key] = []

        dictionary[key] = sorted(set(dictionary[key] + line1 + line2))

print(dictionary)
```

если сам элемент `(i, j)` в анализе участвовать не должен, тогда надо сделать так:

```
    # проанализировать строку и получить нечетные значения
    line1 = [matrix[i][x] for x in range(len(matrix[i])) if matrix[i][x] % 2 and x != j]

    # проанализировать столбец и получить нечетные значения
    line2 = [matrix[x][j] for x in range(len(matrix)) if matrix[x][j] % 2 and x != i]
```

**P.S.**

разобравшись с задачей получается такой код (через упрощение первоначального общего):

```
# получить входные данные от пользователя
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(int(input()))]


# проанализировать данные
dictionary = {}

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if i == len(matrix) // 2:
            # проанализировать строку и получить нечетные значения
            line1 = [matrix[i][x] for x in range(len(matrix[i])) if matrix[i][x] % 2 and x != j]

            # проанализировать столбец и получить нечетные значения
            line2 = [matrix[x][j] for x in range(len(matrix)) if matrix[x][j] % 2 and x != i]

            # добавить в словарь
            key = matrix[i][j]
            if key not in dictionary:
                dictionary[key] = []

            dictionary[key] = sorted(set(dictionary[key] + line1 + line2))

print(dictionary)
```

**P.P.S.**

код можно пооптимизировать, например если перенести условия и вычисления связанные только с `i` под `for i` и над `for j` - т.е. кол-во вычислений можно значительно сократить (на случай, если тест еще и время засекает)

Comment: при первом же тесте неверно(входные данные первого теста и рез-тат есть в вопросе, сейчас добавлю что выводит у вас)

Comment: ключ в значении лишний

Comment: @Андр, я понимаю что у меня не то выводится, я сделал по тому как понял ваше описание. Давайте еще раз 1) составляем матрицу 2) проходим по всем элементам матрицы `(i,j)` и выбираем все элементы той же строки `i` и столбца `j` включая сам элемент `(i, j)` 3) оставляем только нечетные элементы 4) записываем их в словарь где в качестве ключа - значение элемента `(i,j)` - я правильно понял?

Comment: когда идет добавление в значение, то число-ключ добавлять не нужно, а так в остальном правильно

Comment: ключи берутся из строки n//2 только

Comment: @Андр, внес коррективу

Comment: (i, j) участвует в анализе.

Comment: `dictionary[key] + ` - не нужно.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, все, теперь задачу понял - сейчас приведу код

Comment: все равно выдает неверный ответ(прикреплю в вопросе, а также еще более четкую формулировку)

Comment: @Андр, кажется я понял вашу задачу наконец-то :) - смотрите самый последний код

Comment: да, теперь все верно

Comment: @Андр, правильная постановка вопроса позволяет решать задачу быстрее на порядки ;-)

Comment: @Андр, посмотрите PPS - вам может понадобится, если тест проверяет на больших данных и требует каких-то временных ограничений

Comment: @Zhihar хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

это не так работает:

```
a = list(map(int(input())))
```

надо

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

т.е.

1. получить ввод пользователя `input()`
2. разбить полученный текст на слова (через пробел как разделитель) `.split()`
3. к каждому слову применить функцию `int()` через `map` (функция вызывается указанную функцию `int()` к каждому элементу списка и записывает результат в новый список)

Comment: спасибо, не заметил , а что насчет добавления ключа и значения в словарь?

Comment: @Андр, Вот как раз перечитываю уже раз 5 и силюсь понять задачу, можете ее перефразировать? Т.е. я не понял что именно должно быть ключом в словаре, а что значением

Comment: уточнил........

Comment: @Андр, теперь понял - такой вопрос еще - а если одинаковые числа в разных местах и получится 2 разных списка значений - их надо сложить в один?

Comment: да, если в строке встречаются одинаковые числа то значения добавляются в один список

Comment: Обратите внимание на постоянный ключ в вопросе.

Comment: точно! вы верно подметили! должно ведь число по индексу n//2   добавляться, а не n//2

Answer (score 1):

Цикл по средней строке. В цикле собираем нечётные числа из столбцов в словарь. Аналогично собираем числа из средней строки. Элемент в центре "креста" пропускаем - он ключ но в значение не должен попасть. Отдельный цикл множества переводит в упорядоченные списки:

```
def odd_set(iterable):
    return set(v for v in iterable if v % 2 == 1)

n = int(input())
m = tuple(
    tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    for _ in range(n)
)

cols = {}
for j, k in enumerate(m[n // 2]):
    col_set = odd_set(r[j] for i, r in enumerate(m) if i != n // 2)
    row_set = odd_set(vv for jj, vv in enumerate(m[n // 2]) if jj != j)
    cols.setdefault(k, set()).update(col_set | row_set)

print({k: sorted(v) for k, v in cols.items()})
```

> ```
> $ echo -e "3\n1 2 3 4\n3 2 3 1\n4 1 5 3"
> 3
> 1 2 3 4
> 3 2 3 1
> 4 1 5 3
>
> $ echo -e "3\n1 2 3 4\n3 2 3 1\n4 1 5 3" | python strange_matrix.py 
> {3: [1, 3, 5], 2: [1, 3], 1: [3]}
> ```